# ElGamal signature - exploiting fallacious implementation

Tags: elgamal-signature

This question is related to ElGamal signature scheme as defined here 
[ElGamal signature without calculating the inverse](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/630/elgamal-signature-without-calculating-the-inverse)

Show how one could exploit an implementation ElGamal signature scheme in which it is not checked that $0 \leq \gamma \leq p-1.$

As far as I can see, we have to find a $\gamma$ such that $\alpha^{a\gamma-x}\gamma^\delta \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for a message $x$.

Anyone happens to see a good choice of $\gamma$?

Answer (score 1):

As [Wikipedia’s Chinese remainder theorem article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) states:

> The Chinese remainder theorem is a theorem of number theory, which states that if one knows the remainders of the Euclidean division of an integer n by several integers, then one can determine uniquely the remainder of the division of n by the product of these integers, under the condition that the divisors are pairwise coprime.

Using that, you can solve this by finding a $\gamma$ satisfying

$$\gamma \equiv 0 \pmod{p-1}$$

and

$$\gamma \equiv \alpha^x \pmod{p}$$

and you’re done.